# How to Get "Real" NetworkInterfaceType ( or NetworkInterfaceSubType) for Interface type "ppp" in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I know, title is strange, but I explain my problem :

In windows phone code, for detect the type of network, we can use

```
NetworkInterfaceInfo info = nrr.NetworkInterface;
if (info != null)
{
    switch (info.InterfaceType)
    {
        case NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet:
            myInterface = NETWORK_TYPE_ETHERNET;
                break;
        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
            myInterface = NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA;
            switch (info.InterfaceSubtype)
            {
                 case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_HSPA:
                     mySubInterface = NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA_HSPA;
                     break;
                 case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_EDGE:
                     mySubInterface = NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA_EDGE;
                     break;
                 case NetworkInterfaceSubType.Cellular_GPRS:
                     mySubInterface = NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA_GPRS;
                     break;
             }
             break;
     }
 }
```

This code working, and , for sample, where network is CDMA type, I have an access in the subType ; I know if the windowsPhone was in GPRS, EDGE or HSPA...

In C#4, I detect when I connect a DialUp Key in my laptop:

```
if( (NetworkInterfaceType.Ppp == networkCard.NetworkInterfaceType)
   ||(NetworkInterfaceType.GenericModem == networkCard.NetworkInterfaceType)
   ||(NetworkInterfaceType.Slip == networkCard.NetworkInterfaceType)
  ){
   // It's the Dialup Key interface Type.
   }
```

But, I have not informations for an "eventual" subType... 
I want to know if my Key is connected in GPRS, EDGE or HSPA...

Do you know, have to proceed to retrieve the the "real" Network Information Type ( GPRS, EDGE, HSPA... ) when a 3G Key is connected ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by nrr ?

Comment: You could try to use the mobile broadband api => [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323269(v=vs.85).aspx)